# Appropriate object for typical window in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, swt

What object type (eg. JFace, Shell, ApplicationWindow) should I use to create my own window?

[image]

In my plugin, this window will have three 'panels', lots of components and what' s most important I want it **to be on top, till it's closed** - like any other window in Eclipse, so that user can' t do anything else in IDE till he close the window.
The window will be launched after clicking the icon in Eclipse's menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean something like the Eclipse 'Find/Replace' dialog which does not block the main window use a JFace `Dialog` (`org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`).

Set the dialog to be modeless and turn off 'block on open'.

This is what the Find/Replace dialog uses:

```
public FindReplaceDialog(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);

    // .... other code ...

    setShellStyle(getShellStyle() ^ SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.MODELESS);
    setBlockOnOpen(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a command  following tutorial at : `http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html`
Create a handler for the command that opens a swt widget Dialog that is modal. ( use `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` ) populate the dialog with composites that you need.

Comment: Would You please explain why should I use modal Dialog instead of Shell or other components?

Comment: Because in your question you mentioned : what' s most important I want it to be on top, till it's closed - like any other window in Eclipse, so that user can' t do anything else in IDE till he close the window. A modal dialog won't allow the user to do other things on parent composite until it is closed.